# heroku not building my webpack app

Tags: javascript, heroku, webpack

I can't get Heroku to build my webpack react app for some reason.
it seems the built js file dosen't exist. If I put a test.js (not built) in the public folder then the index loads it fine.

Procfile

```
build: npm run prod 
web: node ./server.js
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "export NODE_ENV=development&&npm run dev",
"serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
"dev": " webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port 8080",
"build": "export NODE_ENV=development&& webpack --progress --colors",
"prod": "export NODE_ENV=production&& webpack --progress -p",
"copy": "node copyStatic.js",
"lint": "eslint app/**"
},
"engines": {
"node": "7.7.0",
"npm": "4.4.0"
},
```

webpack.config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');
var PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';

var config = {

entry: {
    app: PROD ? ['babel-polyfill', APP_DIR + '/index.js'] : ['babel-polyfill', APP_DIR + '/index.js', 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080'],
    animations: APP_DIR + '/animations/animations.js'
},
output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: "[name].js",
},
plugins: [],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            use: ['babel-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
                'postcss-loader?sourceMap=inline'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
            use: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: 'file-loader'
        },
        { test: /\.json$/, use: "json-loader" }

    ]

},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        index: 'index.html'
    }
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
        "TweenLite": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite.js'),
        "TweenMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js'),
        "TimelineLite": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js'),
        "TimelineMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax.js')
    }
},
node: {
    //console: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
}
};

module.exports = config;
```

Webpack config

```
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
//////other config
output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: "[name].js",
},
```

In the index.html that is in public folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
```

test.js loads. app.js doesn't. The same setup works fine locally

Comment: Did you check the logs? The build might have failed

Comment: Yes, I can see it building in the logs,         app.js  1.04 MB       0  [emitted]

Comment: and no errors as far as I can see

Comment: What does your package.json file look like? If you have webpack (and others like babel/plugins) under dev-dependencies and you don't setup Heroku specifically, it will skip them. Do you see webpack being run?

Comment: have added the package.json at the top

Comment: it looks like webpack is running. I can see it emitting the app.js and the fonts etc in the logs

Answer (score 1):

This was caused because I had the incorrect buildpack configuration. I switched it to heroku/nodejs in the app settings and it all works fine

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I almost over-complicated this issue, being unfamiliar with Heroku, but sure enough since I'm deploying a Django/Vue stack, only Python was autodetected.